# matDatepicker - css style issue

Tags: angular-material-datetimepicker

what can i do to get this fixed?

```
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="datebird" >
                        <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

[this is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2aW3.png)

[this is what I'm expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL3vc.png)

Comment: Did you figure out what happened here? I'm running into the exact same issue. Pretty sure I have all my styles imported properly as other mat components are looking correct.

Comment: It doesn't feel that correct so I'm not posting it as an answer, but I added this style to my main stylesheet to fix this:

mat-datepicker-toggle button.mat-icon-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: 0px;
  }

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible you have a version of material that’s not up to date.
Before version 15, use and "matSuffix and not "matIconSuffix"

You can have a look here: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/guides/v15-mdc-migration.md